Should I be worried about this warning on a new LED light?
I've just purchased a couple of linkable LED shop lights with plans to replace some existing fluorescents with them. Here's the link: https://www.rona.ca/en/product/utilitech-3-ft-linkable-plug-in-led-shop-light-with-pull-chain-3-000-lm-35-w-cool-white-sh1332-whg-36lf3-67655015
These seemed quite suitable based on the specs but now that I've opened them, I see a warning on the top surface of the light that warns of "Fire Hazard" but doesn't offer any recommendation to reduce the risk. That same surface has a sticker warning that it gets quite hot.
Should I make a point of hanging them from chains so that there is some free air between that top surface and my joists rather than flush-mounting them to them joists? Or take them back and buy different lights that don't have this problem? I really don't want to burn the house down!

The picture on the web site shows the light hanging from chains. That being said, most likely there is no real issue as long as the light isn't fully enclosed - i.e., treated like a recessed light rather than surface mounted.
The specifications on the web page say:

For ceiling and wall mount applications, the product can be surface mounted using two (2) clips and screws (included) or hung using two (2) 12-in chains and harnesses (included)

so it sounds like surface mounting is perfectly fine.
These are really inexpensive, so beware: You may get what you pay for. But at that price, if they last through the 5-year warranty period then you're doing OK.
